# How do I add items to my inventory?

Tags: risk-of-rain-2

I'm using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>~</kbd> to open the console, but I'm not seeing any way to add individual items to my inventory after enabling `cheats 1`.

Comment: There is a mod (https://thunderstore.io/package/Morris1927/RoR2Cheats/) that adds the functionality you are looking for, but the base game does not have those options as far as I know.

Comment: I keep seeing people on YT with like 99x some item which is pretty neat, but I'd prefer not using CheatEngine or any other memory editing tools

Comment: As far as I know, currently, cheat engine, or mods are the only way to do that. That could change in a future update, but for now, it cannot be done with the default game.